# How to get the friendslist of twitter user in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a Twitter based application where I want to fetch the friend list of logged-in Twitter user. I have done a code for this but it is returning error.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    NSMutableDictionary *accountDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:account.username, @"screen_name", nil];

    [accountDictionary setObject:[[[account dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"properties"]] objectForKey:@"properties"] objectForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"user_id"];

    NSURL *followingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=%@&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false",account.username]];

    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:account.username, @"screen_name", nil];

    TWRequest *twitterRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:followingURL
                                                    parameters:parameters
                                                 requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    [twitterRequest setAccount:account];



        NSError *jsonError = nil;
    NSData *responseData;

        NSDictionary *twitterFriends = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];

        [accountDictionary setObject:[twitterFriends objectForKey:@"list"] forKey:@"friends_list"];

    return arr;
```

I get this error:

> { errors = ( { code = 34; message = "Sorry, that page does not exist"; } ); }

Comment: May be you should post this error here???

Comment: it gives this error it does not displays the friend list {
    errors =     (
                {
            code = 34;
            message = "Sorry, that page does not exist";
        }
    );
}

Comment: Are you sure that `followingUrl` composed in a right way?

Answer (score 1):

```
  ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
  ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
  [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
    if (granted==YES) {
        NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
        if (accounts.count) {
            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *str =twitterAccount.accountDescription;
            NSString *newStr = [str substringFromIndex:1];

            id request=nil;
            NSString *profileurl=@"http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?&screen_name=";
            NSString *url1= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",profileurl,newStr];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url1];

            TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url  parameters:nil 
                   requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

            [request setAccount:twitterAccount];
           [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSError *error = nil;
                    NSDictionary *profileimageurl =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error] ;
                    //here you get dictionary of your friends ids


                 });
            }];
```

Comment: Hi Rose i have written ur code but it gives error at this line socialRequestClass requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                          requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                                    URL:url
                                                             parameters:nil

Comment: Use of Undeclared identifier SLServiceTypeTwitter

Comment: just change the SLRequest request into TWRequest class

Comment: and in this  request = [socialRequestClass requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                      requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                                URL:url
                                                         parameters:nil];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20693/discussion-between-rose-and-rani)